# Is there a way to dynamically change the input to a system call in google colab?

Tags: python, string, subprocess, google-colaboratory, cflow

I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically change a subprocess call. Right now I'm running into a problem where I can only input a static string into a subprocess call for google colab and no way to input a string variable.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
for file in list_of_files:
   cflow_data = !cflow file
```

and I am struggling to find a way to get that dynamic string value to be outputted to the subprocess call in google colab. I've tried a variety of methods including:

- subprocess.Popen() followed by .communicate()
- os.system()
- subprocess.call()

and to no avail. If anyone has any insight into this or if it is even possible in Goolge Colab that would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After trying more methods I found a solution.

```
cflow_cmd = ["cflow","-l","/file/path"]
for file in file_list:
   cflow_data = subprocess.check_output(cflow_cmd)
   cflow_data = cflow_data.decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])
```

Which takes the system output and converts it to a byte string and then converts that byte string to a string